# Change working directory of 2 terminals at once

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, command-history

I've typically have gnome-terminal open with ~8 tabs, using 2 consecutive tabs for the same task (one has emacs, the other is used to do git checkins and unittest runs and so).

When changing tasks, I need to move to a new directory - in both tabs. How can I change the work directory of the second tab to the one of the first tab, with as few steps as possible? Preferably keyboard only.

Comment: Do you mean to say that if you are in Tab-1 with /tmp  as CWD and in Tab-2 with /mnt as CWD, then whenever you cd to ~ in TAB-1 then at the same time, TAB-2 MUST get changed to ~ ??

Comment: No, just when I say that I want to change now. Such as a command "change cwd to cwd of tab1".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a work-around: on one tab, record the CWD into a temp file, on the other tabs, cd to the just-saved dir. I would put these two aliases to my .bashrc or .bash_profile:

```
alias ds='pwd > /tmp/cwd'
alias dr='cd "$(</tmp/cwd)"'
```

the ds (dir save) command marks the CWD, and the dr (dir recall) command cd to it. You can do something similar for C-shell.

Comment: This is the simplest solution, and it's the one that will work everywhere - if I'm using gnome terminal or the VTs on alt+1-6. I'll use this. Thanks all others, too

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for, can be achieved by writing a shell script with the help of

> xdotool

Example script that you can use:

```
#!/bin/bash
xdotool type "cd $1
"
xdotool key Ctrl+Next
xdotool type "cd $1
"
```

Comment: As `gnome-terminal` doesn't have support for D-Bus or any other interface there is no elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Try the terminal emulator [terminator](https://launchpad.net/terminator). You can open multiple shells and use the "Broadcast All" feature to send the same command to all of them.

Answer (score 2):

In zsh, you can do the following:

1. Run a command in a shell.
2. Run `fc -AI` in that shell.
3. Run `fc -RI` in another shell.
4. Run `!!` or press <kbd>Up</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the second shell to recall the last command executed in the first shell.

`fc -AI` writes out the command history of the first shell, and `fc -RI` reads it back into the second shell. If you turn on the `inc_append_history`, then the equivalent of `fc -AI` is performed automatically after each command.

If you turn on the `share_history` option, then all history lines are automatically shared between all shell instances, so you can go straight from step 1 to step 4. This can feel invasive.

If you used a relative path to change the directory, you'll need to obtain an absolute path first. One way to do that is to type `cd $PWD` (or just `$PWD` if you have the `auto_cd` option turned on) and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or `C-x *` with some completion settings) to expand `$PWD` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.