# How can I CD in all my terminals simultaneously?

Tags: linux, scripting, terminal

when I use CD in a terminal, I'd like all my open instances to update their directory at the time, so I can perform different tasks in different shells, is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41024/117549

Comment: thanks sounds good, but is there a way to cd automatically without me having to run a command?

Comment: No. You need to set the system to do what you want it to do. There's no default that does this. Some terminal emulators what they do instead is that each new tab will be opened with the same pwd as the current one. Terminator Ctrl + Shift + T does this.